# Is there an option for gradle dependencies to show just the list of libraries

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Is there a short form? Instead of dependencies, can we see just a flat list of libraries used?
`./gradlew -help` doesn't show anything on this. Something like:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.3.7
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0
...
```

Comment: Well, that gets complicated, with different build variants, regular vs. test code, transitive dependencies, etc. `./gradlew app:dependencies` will print a dependency report for an `app` module, but I am uncertain if that is what you want.

Comment: Even with `./gradlew app:dependencies` it will print a tree of dependencies. What I am looking for is a deduped flat list. The use case for me, is to see if a new dependency is added between two commits. Not sure if there is some other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

print the class path that you need to compare - once before and once after the change - then you can do diff

```
task runCP() {
    doLast {
        def runList = configurations.runtimeClasspath.asList()
        def compileOnlyList = configurations.compileOnly.asList()
        println(runList.join("\n"))
        println("----")
        println(compileOnlyList.join("\n"))
        println("====")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if ./gradlew app:dependencies does not work for you, Gradle Enterprise does provide dashboard for comparing 2 builds (for example if you have 2 builds from different commits). From the dashboard you can see if the version was changed, or there are new library added. It also showing all configuration type, e.g. annotationProcessorClasspath, compileClasspath, RuntimeClasspath, etc.
But it is not free.